# Hide upload image fields for the different media upload popups

Tags: customization, admin, uploads, post-thumbnails, media-library

I am trying to change a few of the options in the `Set Featured Image` popup in the Wordpress admin. I can't seem to find anything that determines if the popup window is a `Featured Image` or an `Add Media` popup.

I want to hide **Align** and **Sizes** fields for the `Set Featured Image` popup but have them visible for the `Add Media` panel.

I am able to use the `attachment_fields_to_edit` filter to remove certain fields but not for the two different pop up box types.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm familiar with attachment_fields_to_edit and don't recall ever seeing anything on being able to do modification as granular as you're suggesting. There's a WP global $screen (or is it $screens) that perhaps might help but I'm not too sure.

Have you considered - as hacky as it might sound - doing these things with CSS and/or javascript?